# stored procedure where it retrieve the last column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that retrieves the last IDENTITY for a specified table. Below is what I have so far, which isn't working.

```
CREATE PROCEDRE spGetLast
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE ID = IDENT_CURRENT('users')
    SELECT id as returnvalue
END
```

Comment: maybe u mean to retrieve last row??

Comment: Do you actually have a useful use-case for this? Because this is one of those functions that falls into the category of "as soon as you've obtained your answer, it may no longer be correct"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it and just do the below, as you're not using an [output parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('users')
```

This will have to be handled in code to expect the call to the stored procedure to return a single value.

Otherwise you should use an [output parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetLast
@LastUserId int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @LastUserId = IDENT_CURRENT('users')
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: not thought about this :D

Answer (score 0):

Your way should work.

Not sure why u ask, but here is a bit updated proc (also u can use function instead of proc):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.spGetLast
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret int;

    SELECT @ret = ID
    FROM users 
    WHERE ID = IDENT_CURRENT('users');

    IF (@ret IS NULL) 
        SET @ret = 0;

    RETURN @ret;
END;
```

and here is usage:

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue INT
EXEC @SelectedValue = dbo.spGetLast

SELECT @SelectedValue
```